# Implementing select-like functionality with asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am experiencing a behaviour that I don't understand while trying to implement a `select()`-like functionality with `asyncio` (on Python 3.6):

- I have 2 queues (*A* & *B*) where messages are `Queue.put` by async producers
- I have an async consumer (the *selector*) that polls the queues and takes the first message available (ie. a `select()`-like functionality using `asyncio.wait_for`.

The polling works like this:

```
poll = list(_.get() for _ in queues)
while True:
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tuple(poll), return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

Then, iterating on the `done` futures, I replace the corresponding entries in `poll` with a fresh `Queue.get`:

```
    for f in done:
        try:
            i = poll.index(f._coro)
            ...
            poll[i] = queues[i].get()
```

Now, the odd behaviour that I experience is that the selection works, but some of the `done` futures `.result()` return `None`, and the messages sent through the queues are lost:

```
PUT B ('B', 0)/0
GET B ('B', 0)/0
PUT A ('A', 0)/0
GET A None/0         << ('A', 0) is never received
PUT A ('A', 1)/0
GET A ('A', 1)/0
PUT B ('B', 1)/0
GET B None/0
PUT A ('A', 2)/0
GET A None/0
PUT B ('B', 2)/0
GET B None/0
```

Here's the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio, random

async def queue_generator( name, queue, speed=1 ):
    counter = 0
    while True:
        t = (random.random() + 0.5) * speed
        await asyncio.sleep(t)
        m = (name, counter)
        print ("PUT {0} {1}/{2:d}".format(name, m, queue.qsize()))
        queue.put_nowait(m)
        counter += 1

async def select( *queues ):
    poll = list(_.get() for _ in queues)
    while True:
        # That's the select()-like functionalit
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tuple(poll), return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for f in done:
            i = poll.index(f._coro)
            # That's where sometimes v is None
            v = f.result()
            print ("GET {0} {1}/{2}".format("AB"[i], v, queues[i].qsize()))
            poll[i] = queues[i].get()
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop     = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    queue_a  = asyncio.Queue(10)
    queue_b  = asyncio.Queue(10)
    tasks = (
        loop.create_task(queue_generator("A", queue_a, 3)),
        loop.create_task(queue_generator("B", queue_b, 3)),
        loop.create_task(select(queue_a, queue_b))
    )
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    loop.close()
```

As this happens whenever there is a change in the queue that currently has a message, I assume the problem lies in doing something with the `pending` futures. In fact, adding

```
    for f in pending:
        f.cancel()
```

solves the issue, but I'd like to re-use these futures as much as I can. I suppose the problem comes from the fact that `asyncio.wait_for` silently transforms the list of generators into tasks.

Comment: `get` is a coroutine. You need to use either `await queue.get()` or `queue.get_nowait()`.

Comment: Related: [awaitchannel](https://github.com/pothos/awaitchannel)

Comment: @Vincent isn't the `await asyncio.wait(tuple(poll)...)` doing exactly that? By doing `await queue.get()` sequentially I would block the whole process if let's say the first queue has no message but the second one gets filled.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't dig deeply into what happens, but moving `poll` creating inside loop seems to fix things:

```
async def select( *queues ):
    while True:    
        poll = list(_.get() for _ in queues)  # HERE    
        # That's the select()-like functionalit
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tuple(poll), return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

`poll` is a list of coroutines. Each unique coroutine usually should be awaited once. Doing otherwise may lead to strange things.

Comment: It does fix the issue, and the explanation is that because `Queue.get()` is a coroutine, it must not be awaited twice, which would happen for pending coroutines after the first loop. In any case, `select()` is typically done within the loop, not before. Thanks!